# Endpoint específico para API en Spring con Kotlin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spring, kotlin, endpoint

es la primera vez que escribo aquí a ver si alguien puede ayudarme.

Estoy haciendo un proyecto que consiste en una pequeña tienda Online. Los productos de esta tienda se muestran desde una base de datos que maneja una API que he creado, el Front-End está hecho con React.

Por el momento el mostrar los datos y manejarlos de la base de datos funciona pero quiero hacer lo siguiente: cuando añado elementos al carrito, aparece un formulario con "name" y "mail" que al ser rellenados y se pulsa el botón de "Submit order" mostrará una página con los elementos que había en la cesta junto con el "name" y "mail" a modo de "factura", ahora mismo muestra una página en blanco porque he controlado ese error, pero en barra de dirección muestra bien el pedido que es, por ejemplo: "http://localhost:3000/orders/1", va a la pantalla correcta pero no es capaza de cargar la información. Bien, toda la estructura del Front-End está hecha y funcionando, el único problema es crear un Endpoint en mi API para que me muestre esa página de "factura".

Básicamente lo que necesito enviar es esto:

```
fetchApi("post", "http://localhost:8080/v1/add", {
  order: {
    name,
    mail,
    order_items: cart.map(item => ({
      product_id: item.id,
      quantity: item.quantity
    }))
  }
}
```

Si quito el "order" y unicamente mando el "name" y "mail", funciona, pero si lo dejo tal como está no reconoce el "order" e introduce "null" en la base de datos, pero al menos se que conecta con la base de datos.

La API está hecha con Spring y en Kotling, la tabla ahora mismo la tengo así:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "clients")
data class Client(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    var id: Int?,
    var name: String?,
    var mail: String?,
    var proudct_id: Int?,
    var quantity: Int?
)
```

Este es el Endpoint:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = ["http://localhost:3000"])
@PostMapping("/add", "POST", "application.json")
fun addClient(@RequestBody client: Client): ResponseEntity<Client> {
    val result: Client = clientService.addClient(client)

    return ResponseEntity(result, HttpStatus.OK)
}
```

Y la implementación del mismo por si acaso:

```
override fun addClient(client: Client): Client = clientDao.save(client)
```

Algo más de información.

Pantalla con el producto a comprar con los campos de Nombre y Email:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que me sale:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que debería salir:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La tabla de la base de datos si hago un "Submit order":
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Un saludo.

Comment: Puedes ponernos el controlador que recibe esa llamada HTTP? Porque si dices que funciona, o bien tienes alguna librería de spring por detrás haciendo el trabajo por ti o bien ya lo has hecho. En todo caso comparte el endpoint que tienes hasta ahora.

Comment: Ese es el Endpoint. Y ya digo, si unicamente le digo que mande el mail y el nombre si lo guarda bien, el problema es el objeto entero. He probado a borrar de la base de datos los campos de product_id y quantity pero nada.

Comment: @GerRubio por favor, dale a [edit] y añade el código en la pregunta, no en los comentarios

Comment: @PabloLozano Perdón, no me di cuenta, ya está arreglado.

Comment: Hola, estás esperando en la base de datos product_id y quantity pero no order_items y no veo esa gestión en tu código ni en el modelo.